Performance of transform and back_inserter on a vector
for context, I was trying to find out why a part of our code was running extremely slowly. I managed to isolate it to a single line, with transform on a kinda big vector.
I sped up the execution by using a raw loop instead of transform, but I dont understand why it's faster. Here are the codes:
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    constexpr auto size = 10000000;
    constexpr auto divisor = 256U;
    std::vector<uint16_t> lSource;
    lSource.reserve(size);
    for(auto i = 0U; i < size; ++i)
    {
        lSource.push_back(std::rand());
    }
    
    std::vector<uint8_t> lTarget1, lTarget2, lTarget3;
    
    {
        auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        lTarget1.reserve(size);
        std::transform( lSource.cbegin(), lSource.cend(), std::back_inserter( lTarget1 ), [divisor]( const uint16_t &arg ) { return arg / divisor; } );        
        auto end   = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>( end - start );
        std::cout << "time1:" << elapsed.count() << " ms" << std::endl;
    }
    {
        auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        lTarget2.resize(size);
        for(auto i = 0U; i < lSource.size(); ++i)
        {
            lTarget2[i] = lSource[i] / divisor;
        }
        auto end   = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>( end - start );
        std::cout << "time2:" << elapsed.count() << " ms" << std::endl;
    }
    {
        auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        lTarget3.resize(size);
        std::transform( lSource.cbegin(), lSource.cend(), lTarget3.begin(), [divisor]( const uint16_t &arg ) { return arg / divisor; } );        
        auto end   = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>( end - start );
        std::cout << "time3:" << elapsed.count() << " ms" << std::endl;
    }
    
    if(lTarget1!= lTarget2 )
    {
        std::cout << "different result1";
    }
    if(lTarget1!= lTarget3 )
    {
        std::cout << "different result2";
    }
}

See here: https://onlinegdb.com/Y6Nnr_vZZ5
Results:
time1:416 ms (reserve + transform + back_inserter)
time2:71 ms (resize + raw loop)
time3:166 ms (resize + transform)

The first part, reserve the vector, then use transform with back_inserter is really slow.
I can speed up the execution by resizing instead of reserving and not using back_inserter
And I can speed up even more by just using a raw loop.
But I have no idea why. Any ideas?
EDIT following comments - Timings:
on onlinegdb.com without any argument:
time1:416 ms (reserve + transform + back_inserter)
time2:71 ms (resize + raw loop)
time3:166 ms (resize + transform)

with -Ofast
time1:10 ms
time2:13 ms
time3:8 ms

with -O2
time1:9 ms
time2:11 ms
time3:9 ms

on my computer with visual studio 2022 with /O2:
time1:36 ms
time2:20 ms
time3:8 ms


What are the optimization settings you used when you compiled the application?  Any question that concerns the speed of C++ code must be accompanied by the optimization settings used.  If you are timing unoptimized code or a "debug" build, the timings you are showing are meaningless.

Results on optimized build: 16ms, 10ms, 10ms

When you use back_inserter, and the vector has no aquired memory, then every time you fill up the vector it will have to allocate a new bigger buffer, copy/move evrything from the old buffer to the new buffer, then get rid of the old buffer.  That will happen geometrically but it will still have a noticeable effect.  If you know the size it's going to be in the end you should reserve that space.

@NathanOliver There is in fact a reserve or resize call in all the relevant places.

Enable optimisations and the results are quite different. On online gdb I get all 3 at around 10ms (though I don't think you can share a link with compiler options there).

@IgorTandetnik Ah, I missed those, although resize doesn't do what the OP wants since it leaves the first half of the vector with zero initialized elements.

Add -Ofast and the results are flipped. https://www.onlinegdb.com/fork/Y6Nnr_vZZ5. In other words, there is no significant difference

@NathanOliver Everything is fine. reserve() is used in case 1 with back_inserter, resize() is used in cases 2 and 3 with raw loop and direct transform()

rule #0 of performance tweaking: Let the compiler do it.

@NathanOliver No it does not. The version that uses resize doesn't use back_inserter, but overwrites the elements in place.

alright, getting more coffee, code reading is not so good right now.

Even with reserve, the code to check that size < capacity might not be optimized out.

std::transform comes with an execution policy, since ALL your transformations are independent you can parallelize it right away.  But then you have to transform to a preallocated vector and not use back_inserter.

Thanks for the feedbacks, I edited my questions with timings dependings on optimisation and also msvc

Please remember that writing a good performance test is hard. There are couple serous problems: you need optimized code, but you also do not what that optimizer would remove large pert of tested code. Making accurate time measurements is also not straight forward. Your code sample show that you are not aware about this problems, please see this.

Better performance test clang gcc. Resize then transform to regular iterator wins.
